# Is there a predecessor to the new command CreateFile?

Tags: files-and-directories

In version 10.4 the command `CreateFile` was introduced:

[CreateFile documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateFile.html?q=CreateFile)

I am using version 10.3.1 on a Raspberry Pi. I have not found any command which does what `CreateFile` does. Is there one?

In order to use `OpenRead`, `OpenWrite`, `ReadList` and `Close`, I have created an empty text file in a Text Editor first. But of course I would like to be able to create the file from inside *Mathematica*. Should I use something like

```
Export["file.ext",{}]
```

if I want to make an empty file?

Comment: The predecessor to [`CreateFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateFile.html) is [`CreateTemporary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateTemporary.html), but it was more limited - it only creates a temporary file.  `OpenWrite` and `OpenAppend` will create a file if it doesn't exist.  So will `Export["file.ext", "","Text"]`

Comment: I dont follow the issue, `OpenWrite` creates the file if it does not exist.  `Close[OpenWrite["file"]]` creates an empty file.   (unless there is something peculiar about the Raspberry Pi os. I suppose)

Comment: @george2079 Why not give it as an answer? It is a perfect answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @Alexey Popkov. The readability is improved. By the way, "inside *Mathematica*" is correct grammar. Here "inside" is used a preposition in its own right. In "I cleaned the inside of the car", "inside" is used as a noun. In American English "Inside of" is sometimes used as a preposition, but I am using something more like British English. I know that my spaces preceding question marks and exclamation marks are not standard - I have borrowed that convention from French :) I feel awkward when the letters touch those two particular punctuation marks !

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the lesson (I have removed the redundant "of") and the explanation. I always wondered where it comes from when seeing the spaces before question marks and exclamation marks. I feel them as "floating" and not connected to the sentence, so it awkward to me :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The new function [`CreateFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateFile.html) has two main tasks,

1. `CreateFile[]` - will create a file in the "default area for temporary files on your computer".  Like

```
CreateFile[]
(* "/var/folders/yy/3fh5ypq11nx5032xgf6xy36w000_6y/T/m000005141861" *)
```

2. `CreateFile["filename"]` will create an empty file with the given name.

Prior to version 10.4, you could get the effect of (1) via [`CreateTemporary[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateTemporary.html).  (2) could be achieved by any of the methods in this (nonexhaustive, I'm sure) list:

```
Close@OpenWrite@"file1";
Close@OpenAppend@"file2";
WriteString["file3", ""];
Export["file4", "", "Text"];
Export["file5", {}, "Text"];
Run["touch file6"];
FileByteCount /@ {"file1", "file2", "file3", "file4", "file5", "file6"}
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```